# How to pre-fill fields in a quick create form from the parent entity in Dynamics CRM 2016?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

In Dynamics CRM 2016, how can I pre-fill lookup fields in a quick create form based on the same fields being on the parent entity, without using JavaScript?

Comment: How can this this be flagged as a duplicate?  The quick create forms behave very differently to the standard forms - especially with the new UI.

Comment: I think maybe because the solution of adding a mapping is the same regardless of whether the form is standard or a quick create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the solution-> child entity-> 1:N relationships, there is a section for Mappings within each relationship where we can specify which fields will be pre-filled with the content of the parent (primary entity).

Just had to add a new mapping with the source field from the parent and the target from the child.